# Need to set multiple canned ACLs on S3 item

Tags: amazon-s3, acl

We have a service where customers of ours give us access to their S3 buckets and we push items into those S3 buckets. We need to be able to do 2 things:

1. Set the permissions on the item to be publicly readable
2. Set the owner of the bucket to have full permissions to the item

Here is what I already know:

I cannot have 2 canned-ACLs with the PUT

Problem:

I "could" set ACL headers, but AFAIK there is no way to set the "owner-has-full-permissions" via header without knowing information about the owner (Like cannonical_id or email), correct? Is there a "uri" version of "owner-has-full-permissions" like there is for "public-read" (e.g. "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers")?

I don't want to have to make 2 separate calls (one to get the buckets owner info) and one to put the item with both permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the following code can get the permissions you require.

```
AccessControlList accessControlList = new AccessControlList();
accessControlList.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read);
accessControlList.grantPermission(new CanonicalGrantee(s3Client.getS3AccountOwner()
    .getId()), Permission.FullControl);
putReq.setAccessControlList(accessControlList);
```